# psycopg2 ProgrammingError - Parameters with Hyphens

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

```
sql = 'select "productID" from "Barneys_Output" where "designerID" = %s' %self.id
db = self.cursor.execute(sql)
```

`self.id` is something like `N-1f27va5` (always has a hyphen). Assume that the cursor and connection is already established. I get this error saying `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "f27va5"`. Is there a problem with psycopg2 reading hyphens or something? What would be the solution in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement will look like

```
select "productID" from "Barneys_Output" where "designerID" = N-1f27va
```

This isn't valid SQL syntax. You shouldn't format the string by yourself. It is better that PyGreSQL does that for you:

```
sql = 'select "productID" from "Barneys_Output" where "designerID" = %s'
db = self.cursor.execute(sql, (self.id, ))
```

This will escape strings correctly. This should produce something like

```
select "productID" from "Barneys_Output" where "designerID" = 'N-1f27va'
```

While this example is very simple, you should not mask your parameters yourself, because PyGreSQL handles special characters or other data types like `date` or `datetime` correctly.

Comment: I am not sure but this also may reduce the risks of SQL injection.

Comment: @Tahtakafa Definitely